# Using group in regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am taking an input text and a pattern from the user. Text is in the tabular format. Depending on the users choice, I want the code to give me all the columns of the row the user has selected using pattern.
Eg.
Text:

```
Name            Age            Sex          Address
ABC             22             Male         Bangalore
XYZ             34             Female       Hyderabad
```

Now the user gives input as 'XYZ' and the text given above. I want a code that would fetch me all the results i.e. 34,Female,Hyderabad in a list or in different variables. I tried using group but I am not able to understand how would I use group in this. Since 'XYZ' is given by the user, assumne it to be stored in a variable 'pattern'

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a TSV parser?

Comment: I agree, don't use a regex for this. The [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is ideal for this. If `Name` is a unique identifier, then you just need a `csv.reader()` object and apply `{row[0]: row[1:] for row in reader}` to it.

Comment: @Biffen am new to python and I did not know about it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this :

```
data=[]

inp=input()
data.append(inp.split(' '))

"""Now your first entry is data[0]
To get name , use data[0][0]
To get age , use data[0][1]
To get sex , use data[0][2]
and so on....
For 2nd Entry use :
To get name , use data[1][0]
To get age , use data[1][1]
To get sex , use data[1][2] """
```

You can put the code in a loop to get n entries.
Hope this helps